# Chrome Extension notifications rejects image

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm developing an extension that needs to show an image in a notification.

I'm receiving the message:

> Image resource provided for notification type != image

The current code is as follows:

```
chrome.notifications.create('', {
    type: 'basic',
    title: 'New Video: ' + video.title,
    message: 'You got a new video!!!',
    iconUrl: 'imgs/notification.jpg',
    imageUrl: video.thumbnails.notification.url
});
```

Comment: "URLs can be a data URL, a blob URL, or a URL relative to a resource within this extension's .crx file", what's the content of `video.thumbnails.notification.url`?

Comment: The problem is not the URL. Is the type of the notification. Once I replaced the type from 'basic' to 'image' the notification worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification must have the type 'image' to show an image.

The working code is

```
chrome.notifications.create('', {
    type: 'image',
    title: 'New Video: ' + video.title,
    message: 'You got a new video!!!',
    iconUrl: 'imgs/notification.jpg',
    imageUrl: video.thumbnails.notification.url
});
```

Comment: I was having the same issue as the asker. I think they put the wrong code on the documentation page.